# Minimal setup to test a flask application

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I'm trying to create a minimal setup to test a flask application.

At the moment I have a folder for my application

```
root/
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        app.py
```

my `app.py` file is a very minimal flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now, following [this guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/testing/) I'm trying to add some tests in a dedicated folder:

```
root/
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        app.py
    tests/
        tests.py
```

Where `tests.py` has the following content:

```
import os
import myapp
import unittest
import tempfile

class FlaskrTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.db_fd, myapp.app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()
        myapp.app.testing = True
        self.app = myapp.app.test_client()
        with myapp.app.app_context():
            myapp.init_db()

    def tearDown(self):
        os.close(self.db_fd)
        os.unlink(myapp.app.config['DATABASE'])

    def test_empty_db(self):
        print(myapp)
        resp = self.app.get('/index')
        assert resp.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now I would like to install and change as little things as possible and being able to run my tests.

What is your suggestion?

In the page I linked they suggest to use pytest but it's yet another tool and I would prefer to understand everything from the basics and avoid adding too much stuff.

If I do the simplest thing that comes to my mind: inside the `root` folder, run:

```
python tests/tests.py
```

But I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'

but I'm not exactly sure about how to use the myapp module in my test in my current configuration.

Comment: Have you tried adding you directory to python path? Like `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".."))` before importing the module in tests?

Comment: I didn't. Thank you for the tip, it helped!